# How can I make a WinForms Form work as a DockableContent in AvalonDock?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop, avalondock

I am able to use WinForms controls, but not an entire form:

```
        var foo = new DockableContent();
        foo.Title = "Foo";
        foo.Name = "FooName";


        var c = new WindowsAppFramework.RenderTargetUserControl();
        c.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        c.AutomaticUpdateFPS = 60;

        var host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        host.Child = c;

        foo.Content = host;
        foo.ShowAsDocument(dockManager);
        foo.Focus();
```

Is it possible to use an entire Form?  I want to make use of existing Forms in the Application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn a form into a child control:

```
  var frm = new Form1();
  frm.TopLevel = false;
  frm.Visible = true;
  frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Which essentially turns it into a UserControl.